# Android resurce linking failed issue in XML file on Wear OS

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, wear-os

I'm developping watch faces on Wear OS. I have a core module used in many different projects, that contains all the common code.

In particular, I have this xml file for complication style:

```
<drawable
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="android.support.wearable.complications.rendering.ComplicationDrawable"
    app:backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:borderColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:borderDashGap="0dp"
    app:borderDashWidth="1dp"
    app:borderRadius="52dp"
    app:borderStyle="solid"
    app:borderWidth="3dp"
    app:highlightColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:iconColor="@color/white"
    app:rangedValuePrimaryColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:rangedValueRingWidth="2.5dp"
    app:rangedValueSecondaryColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:textColor="@color/white"
    app:textSize="12sp"
    app:textTypeface="sans-serif-condensed"
    app:titleColor="@color/white"
    app:titleSize="12sp"
    app:titleTypeface="sans-serif">

    <ambient
        app:highlightColor="@color/white"
        app:iconColor="@color/white"
        app:titleColor="@color/white"
        app:borderColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rangedValuePrimaryColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rangedValueRingWidth="1dp"
        app:rangedValueSecondaryColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:textColor="@color/white"
    />
</drawable>
```

and the file is called like this:

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.custom_complication_styles) as ComplicationDrawable
```

Initially, all went well (in apperearance) and my project was compiling just fine (in debug mode). But then I noticed that Android Studio was complaining about a gradle dependency of my core module. He wanted my to replace

```
    api "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1"
    api "com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1"
```

by

```
    compileOnly "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1"
    compileOnly "com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1"
```

The problem is that by doing that, it now triggers the following error:

> AAPT: error: attribute borderColor (aka com.myapp:borderColor) not found.

The same error is fired for almost every attribute in the above xml file.

Moreover, the error is linked to the auto-generated intermediate file, and not the original one. I don't know if it is normal. And on that file, I have this error mentionned:
[image]

In case it's relevant, here is the complete gradle file of my core module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOL_VERSION

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'bs23'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file("$rootDir/keystore/android.jks")
            storePassword '123456'
        }
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file("$rootDir/keystore/debug.keystore")
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
    api 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    compileOnly "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:$wearable_version"
    compileOnly "com.google.android.support:wearable:$wearable_version"
    api 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
    api "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
    api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    //RX
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

So moving back and forth between 'api' and 'compileOnly' makes my project compile or not. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your projects are accessing classes/values that belongs to `com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1` and/or `com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1` through your core module. I don't think this is a direct violation of any best practices, so your options are to:

1. Keep using api to expose the wearable:wearable and support:wearable functionality to projects using your core module. And suppress/ignore the warning.
2. Switch to compileOnly in your core module and add a dependency (to wearable:wearable and/or support:wearable) in the project that needs it. You might want to extract the version number to a central place to make sure that they are always using the same.